# 404 error for CSS file in Flask Application

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I am unable to find exact path of .css file in my flask app. Following is relevant code

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>An App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="heading"><h3>App</h3></div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>


+app
  +static
    style.css
+templates
__init__.py
forms.py
models.py
views.py
db_repository
.gitignore
app.db
config.py
db_create.py
```

The one with `+` sign are folders

**Update**:

I tried this in `__init__.py`, same result

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app._static_folder = os.path.abspath("static/style.css")
print os.path.abspath(app._static_folder)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import views, models
```

The link `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/style.css` gives 404 error

Comment: try adding the path when u create the app,`app._static_folder = <path_to_static_directory>`

Comment: @sk11 question updated. Still same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Static should be on the same level as templates, not under app. Have you tried that?

Comment: You were right. I did not notice static one was out of `app` folder thus different from `templates`

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I you want to change the route to the static asset's folder you could do:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='app/static')
```

check this [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/)